# Vertical text in table with no vertical lines

Tags: tables, booktabs

I want to modify this table in this way:
[image]

Here is my MWE, in which I tried to achieve it with no success.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}    % \extrarowheight macro
\usepackage{graphicx} % \rotatebox macro
\usepackage{multirow} % \multirow macro
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule
\begin{document}


%Before

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccc@{}}
\toprule
Expert & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{Prediction}\\
\cmidrule(l){2-5}
& Blah & BlahBlahBlahBlah & BlahBlahBlah & BlahBlahBlah \\
\midrule
Blah & $10$ & $10$ & $10$ & $10$\\ 
BlahBlahBlahBlah & $10$ & $10$ & $10$ & $10$\\ 
BlahBlahBlah & $10$ & $10$ & $10$ & $10$\\ 
BlahBlahBlah & $10$ & $10$ & $10$ & $10$\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
}

\vspace{5cm}

%After
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|@{}ccccc@{}}
\toprule
\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Expert}}} &  & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{Prediction}\\
\cmidrule(l){2-5}
& Blah & BlahBlahBlahBlah & BlahBlahBlah & BlahBlahBlah \\
\midrule
Blah & $10$ & $10$ & $10$ & $10$\\ 
BlahBlahBlahBlah & $10$ & $10$ & $10$ & $10$\\ 
BlahBlahBlah & $10$ & $10$ & $10$ & $10$\\ 
BlahBlahBlah & $10$ & $10$ & $10$ & $10$\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

Someone knows how to get it? Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Thank you for providing a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you added an additional column, you need to add an additional `&` to the main content to skip over the new column. To skip the vertical rule over the rows where it is not desired I used `\multicolumn{2}{c}{}`.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}    % \extrarowheight macro
\usepackage{graphicx} % \rotatebox macro
\usepackage{multirow} % \multirow macro
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule
\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{|c|ccccc@{}}
\cmidrule[0.9pt](l){3-6}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{Prediction}\\
\cmidrule(l){3-6}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}& Blah & BlahBlahBlahBlah & BlahBlahBlah & BlahBlahBlah \\
\cmidrule(l){2-6}
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Expert}}
&Blah & $10$ & $10$ & $10$ & $10$\\ 
&BlahBlahBlahBlah & $10$ & $10$ & $10$ & $10$\\ 
&BlahBlahBlah & $10$ & $10$ & $10$ & $10$\\ 
&BlahBlahBlah & $10$ & $10$ & $10$ & $10$\\ 
\cmidrule[0.9pt](l){2-6}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy with one supplementary column and a `\rotatebox` command. Let me point that your `makebox`command is quite unnecessary and that the minpage environment produces a too tight vertical spacing. But perhaps you have serious reasons not to use a table environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}

\usepackage{array} % \extrarowheight macro
\usepackage{graphicx} % \rotatebox macro
\usepackage{multirow} % \multirow macro
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule

\begin{document}

Before: \\

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccc@{}}
\toprule
Expert & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{Prediction}\\
\cmidrule(l){2-5}
& Blah & BlahBlahBlahBlah & BlahBlahBlah & BlahBlahBlah \\
\midrule
Blah & $10$ & $10$ & $10$ & $10$\\
BlahBlahBlahBlah & $10$ & $10$ & $10$ & $10$\\
BlahBlahBlah & $10$ & $10$ & $10$ & $10$\\
BlahBlahBlah & $10$ & $10$ & $10$ & $10$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
}

\vspace{5cm}

After: \\

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}c <{\enspace }@{}ccccc@{}}
\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{3-6}
 & & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{Prediction}\\
\cmidrule(l){3-6}
 & & Blah & BlahBlahBlahBlah & BlahBlahBlah & BlahBlahBlah \\
\cmidrule{2-6}
\multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\enspace Expert}} & Blah & $10$ & $10$ & $10$ & $10$\\
 & BlahBlahBlahBlah & $10$ & $10$ & $10$ & $10$\\
 & BlahBlahBlah & $10$ & $10$ & $10$ & $10$\\
 & BlahBlahBlah & $10$ & $10$ & $10$ & $10$\\
\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{2-6}
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]